# What's difference between pthread_mutex_trylock's return and pthread_mutex_lock's return

Tags: c, linux, unix, pthreads

I read the Linux man page and OpenGroup for `pthread_mutex_lock` and get this:

> If successful, the pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock()
>   functions shall return zero, otherwise, an error number shall be
>   returned to indicate the error.
>
> The pthread_mutex_trylock() function shall return zero if a lock on the mutex object referenced by mutex is acquired. Otherwise,
>   an error number is returned to indicate the error.

1. I was confused by these two lines. If you both return zero when sucess and return non-zero when error, where do they write this in two lines?
2. I know mutex can be lock and unlock, but what does *a mutex is acquired* mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this context *mutex is acquired* means that there was no thread holding the lock at the time. If the mutex is recursive, the call to `pthread_mutex_trylock()` will succeed unless it has been recursively locked too many times.

You can think of `pthread_mutex_trylock()` as a non-blocking call, where if it would have blocked, it returns with an error instead. If it returns success, it means you have the lock as if `pthred_mutex_lock()` returned successfully. If it fails with `EBUSY` it means some other is holding the lock. If it fails with `EOWNERDEAD`, the lock was held by another thread, but that thread had died (getting the lock actually succeeded, but the current data state may not be consistent). If it fails with `EAGAIN` it was locked recursively too many times. There are other failure reasons, but in those cases, the lock has not been acquired.

```
int error = pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock);
if (error == 0) {
    /*... have the lock */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
} else if (error == EBUSY) {
    /*... failed to get the lock because another thread holds lock */
} else if (error == EOWNERDEAD) {
    /*... got the lock, but the critical section state may not be consistent */
    if (make_state_consistent_succeeds()) {
        pthread_mutex_consistent(&lock);
        /*... things are good now */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    } else {
        /*... abort()? */
    }
} else {
    switch (error) {
    case EAGAIN: /*... recursively locked too many times */
    case EINVAL: /*... thread priority higher than mutex priority ceiling */
    case ENOTRECOVERABLE:
                 /*... mutex suffered EOWNERDEAD, and is no longer consistent */
    default:
        /*...some other as yet undocumented failure reason */
    }
}
```

The `EAGAIN`, `EINVAL`, `ENOTRECOVERABLE`, and `EOWNERDEAD` also happen with `pthread_mutex_lock()`. For more information, consult the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) and [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_trylock).

Comment: So when we relock the mutex  in `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` mode didn't always mean we acquired the mutex ?

Comment: If the mutex is recursive, `pthread_mutex_trylock()` won't fail as long as the mutex is in a valid state.

Comment: So can I understand `acquired a mutex` is the same as `lock mutex suceess` ?

Comment: @jxh: For a recursive mutex that's also robust, `pthread_mutex_trylock` could "fail" with `EOWNERDEAD` (although that means the mutex is now acquired by the calling thread).

Comment: @R..: Thanks, did not know about that. Those darned standards bodies constantly updating standards...

Comment: @jxh: Trylock on a recursive mutex can also fail (ironically, with `EAGAIN`) if you've already locked it too many times (probably 2^31-1 times). And it can also fail in the case of a mutex using priority protection protocol.

Comment: @R..: I think I covered all the failure cases, although some are overlapped with failures that are also seen when `pthread_mutex_lock()`, so they technically did not need to be covered in this answer.

Comment: @jxh: You messed up one detail: the error code is not in `errno`. `pthread_*` functions *return* the error code directly.