# pthread_mutex_trylock() use to wait , until other lock has not released

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

In my code I am using pthread_mutx_trylock() to check thread 1 has completed his 
job and release the mutexlock or not ?Please let me know either its a valid way or not ?

In Thread 1:

```
     pthread_mutex_lock(&sync_wait);
     // Waiting for return type.
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&sync_wait);
```

In Thread 2:

```
    while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&sync_wait) == 0) {
          }; // Wait until other thread has lock

    // Waiting till thread 1 sync wait lock has not released.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sync_wait);
```

Comment: In the real program, is `// Waiting for return type.` some other code, or is it just a comment, and the lock and unlock operations happen next to each other?

Answer (score 1):

From manual Page

> The pthread_mutex_trylock() function shall return zero if a lock on
>   the mutex object referenced by mutex is acquired. Otherwise, an error
>   number is returned to indicate the error.

```
// so this will loop forever once you aquire lock
    while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&sync_wait) == 0) {
              }; // Wait until other thread has lock
```

**Edit:**

This section of code should handle your scenario

```
while ( int ret = pthread_mutex_trylock( &sync_wait) )
{
  // Unable to get Mutex probably some other thread aquired it
  // sleep for some time usleep or even better use pthread_mutex_timedlock
  // Ideally possible ret values should have been handled but for now
  // this will do
}
```

and yes `pthread_mutex_unlock( );`once done with work

here is the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_trylock)
also there is a question on so about difference between `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_trylock` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393097/whats-difference-between-pthread-mutex-trylocks-return-and-pthread-mutex-lock)
this is another [example of handling multiple return values from pthread_try_lock()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18393131/1853605)

Comment: I want to wait until in thread 1 has the lock when thread 1 release the lock this while loop should end .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wake up a specific thread once another thread reaches a certain point in its execution, mutexes are typically not the appropriate synchronization primitive.  Alternatives are:

- Barriers and the [`pthread_barrier_wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_barrier_wait.3p.html) function
- Conditional variables and the [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_wait.3p.html) and [`pthread_cond_signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_signal.3p.html) functions
- Possibly semaphores and the [`sem_wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3p.html) and [`sem_post`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3p.html) functions